# How can I refresh jQuery DataTable without Page Refresh?

Tags: jquery, datatables, reset

I am using a multi-column search functionality in my Datatable, I also have a reset button which clears all the searches and gets the DataTable to it's default state.

That works fine.

But I want to know how to reset the datatable without refreshing the page..??

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

The following is the html for Reset Button:

```
<button class="Reset form-control" id="reset">Reset table to Original State</button>
```

The following is to reset table to original state

```
 oTable.fnDraw();
```

Answer (score 1):

After a quick google search I found a function you could use the reset/reload the table. You can do the by using AJAX and the ajax.reload() function from the datatables plugin.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

table.ajax.reload( function ( json ) {
    $('#myInput').val( json.lastInput );
} );
```

Documentation: [datatables ajax.reload()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload())

Comment: Is there any cdn to be added to use ajax.reload? @gwesseling

Comment: I don' t think so. ajax.reload() should work if you have JQuery and datatables. See the link I added in my solution as an example.

Comment: `ajax.reload()` is only available in v1.10 and since the OP has used v1.9 syntax, I am assuming that v1.10 functionality is not available.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the datatable `fnDraw()` function in the button click event:

```
$('#reset').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    oTable.fnDraw();
});
```

This assumes that you have already assigned the datatable object to var `oTable`. Also you must have reset the search fields before calling `fnDraw()` otherwise you will just perform another search.

Comment: This works fine. But I don't want the page to reload, it should be on the client side. @markpsmith

Comment: Is the button in a form? normally, reset buttons are declared with `type="reset"` which would prevent a refresh. You haven't done that so you will need to add `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: This only resets the textbox values.. But the default values of the datatable before search is performed aren't retained upon reset button click..

Comment: To be honest, you've not given us much to work with - can you post some more code? The form and the datatables code would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Code for DataTables:

```
var oTable;
var asInitVals = new Array();

$(document).ready(function () {
    oTable = $('#webgrid').dataTable({
    //"sDom": 'C<"clear">lfrtip',
        sDom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'copyHtml5',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: [0, ':visible']
                }
            },
            {
                extend: 'excelHtml5',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: ':visible'
                }
            },
            'colvis'
        ],
        "sSearch": "Search all columns:",
        "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
        colReorder: true,
    });
    //To reset table to original state
    $('#reset').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        oTable.fnDraw();
    });
    //oTable.fnDraw();

    $("tfoot input").keyup(function () {
        /* Filter on the column (the index) of this element */
        oTable.fnFilter(this.value, $("tfoot input").index(this));
    });
    /*
     * Support functions to provide a little bit of 'user friendlyness' to the textboxes in
     * the footer
     */
    $("tfoot input").each(function (i) {
        asInitVals[i] = this.value;
    });});
```

This is the form containing a WebGrid and the Reset Button :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Persons", "Welcome", FormMethod.Get, new { @class = "Search-form", @id = "form1" }))

{
<div id="DivGrid">
    @{
var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model, canPage: false,
        defaultSort: "Employee_ID", columnNames: new[] { "Employee_ID", "First_Name", "Last_Name", "Date_Of_Birth" });
if (Model.Count() > 0)
{
        @grid.Table(tableStyle: "PGrid", headerStyle: "Header", footerStyle: "Footer", alternatingRowStyle: "altRow", htmlAttributes: new { id = "webgrid" }, columns: grid.Columns(
                 grid.Column("Employee_ID", "Employee ID",
            format: @<text>  <span class="display-mode">@item.Employee_ID </span>
            <label id="EmployeeID" class="edit-mode">@item.Employee_ID</label> </text>, style: "col2Width EmployeeID"),

            grid.Column("First_Name", "First Name", format: @<text>  <span class="display-mode">
                <label id="lblFirstName">@item.First_Name</label>
            </span> <input type="text" id="FirstName" value="@item.First_Name" class="edit-mode" name="firstname" /></text>, style: "col2Width"),

            grid.Column("Last_Name", "Last Name", format: @<text> <span class="display-mode">
                <label id="lblLastName">@item.Last_Name</label>
            </span>  <input type="text" id="LastName" value="@item.Last_Name" class="edit-mode" name="lastname" /> </text>, style: "col2Width"),

            grid.Column("Date_Of_Birth", "Date Of Birth", format: item => ((item.Date_Of_Birth == null) ? "" : item.Date_Of_Birth.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")), style: "DateOfBirth"),
            grid.Column(header: "Action", canSort: false, style: "action", format: @<text>
                <button class="edit-user display-mode glyphicon glyphicon-edit"> Edit</button>
                <button class="display-mode delete-item glyphicon glyphicon-trash"> Delete</button>
                <button class="save-user edit-mode glyphicon glyphicon-save"> Save</button>
                <button class="cancel-user edit-mode glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"> Cancel</button></text>)));
    <table class='container'>
        <tfoot class='filters multipleSearch col-md-12'>
            <tr class="tBoxes">
                <th class="txtBoxWidth">
                    <input class='txtBox1 form-control' placeholder='Employee Id' />
                    @*<input type="text" name="Employee Id" placeholder='Employee Id' class="search_init" />*@
                </th>
                <th class="txtBoxWidth">
                    <input class='txtBox2 form-control' placeholder='First Name' />
                </th>
                <th class="txtBoxWidth">
                    <input class='txtBox3 form-control' placeholder='Last Name' />
                </th>
                <th class="txtBoxWidth">
                    <input class='txtBox4 form-control' placeholder='Date of Birth' />
                </th>
                <th>
                    <input type="reset" value="Reset table to Original State" class="Reset btn btn-sm"  />
                           @*<button type="reset" class="Reset form-control" id="reset">Reset table to Original State</button>*@
                </th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
        <br>
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
$(tableId).dataTable().fnDraw();
```